# How to create static app shortcut for android 7.1 app?

Tags: android-7.1-nougat

like this I want to do with my own shortcuts. And to open particular activity depending on shortcut type

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q87SO.png

Comment: https://developer.android.com/preview/shortcuts.html#static

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create android project with target api level 25
2. Create an xml named `shortcuts.xml` under res, inside xml directory and add following code in it:  (to create static shortcuts)

   ```
   <shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <shortcut
       android:enabled="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/static_shortcut_disabled_message"       
       android:shortcutId="static"
       android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/static_shortcut_long_label"
       android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/static_shortcut_short_label">
        <intent        
          android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
          android:targetClass="<Fully_Qualified_Activity_Name>"
          android:targetPackage="Package_Name_Of_Activity" /> 
       </shortcut>
   </shortcuts>
   ```

Inside `Manifest.xml` add this meta-data tag for your activity:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
    android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
```

And test it by long pressing app icon.

Comment: Note that you have `”` and `“` in there, this should be `"` or not?

Comment: What if you have different targetPackage for different productFlavours?

Comment: and how to catch shortcut clicks?